# lottie-react useLottieInteractivity play once?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lottie

I'm trying to have an animation with lottie that will only trigger once when reaching a certain
visibility level. My problem is, the animation always loop with useLottieInteractivity and I'm not sure how to make it play only one time.

So this is what my code look like:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { useLottie, useLottieInteractivity } from "lottie-react"
import CMS from "../components/remdash/animations/cms.json"

const LottieBlock: React.FC<any> = props => {

  const options = {
    animationData: CMS,
  }

  const LottieAnimation = () => {
    const lottieObj = useLottie(options)
    const Animation = useLottieInteractivity({
      lottieObj,
      mode: "scroll",
      actions: [
        {
          visibility: [0, 0.4],
          type: "seek",
          frames: [0],
        },
        {
          visibility: [0.4, 0.5],
          type: "play",
          frames: [0, 60],
        },
        {
          visibility: [0.6, 1],
          type: "stop",
          frames: [60],
        },
      ]
    })

    return Animation
  }

  const showVisualization = (
    <div className="relative w-full h-full">
        <React.Fragment>
          <LottieAnimation />
        </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  )

  return showVisualization
}

export default LottieBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable the `loop` and `autoplay` attributes then use the `play()` function.

Comment: Can this be done with useLottieInteractivity or do I have to make a custom function to detect the scroll and then trigger the play() function ?
I'm sorry I think it's like a very basic question but I can't find anything about it in the documation for "useLottieInteractivity"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
actions: [
        {
          visibility: [0, 0.4],
          type: "seek",
          frames: [0],
        },
        {
          visibility: [0.4, 0.5],
          type: "play",
          frames: [0, 60],
        },
        {
          visibility: [0.6, 1],
          type: "stop",
          frames: [60],
        },
      ]
```

with

```
actions: [
        {
          visibility: [0, 0.4],
          type: "seek",
          frames: [0],
        },
        {
          visibility: [0.4, 0.5],
          type: "playOnce",
          frames: [0, 60],
        },
        {
          visibility: [0.6, 1],
          type: "stop",
          frames: [60],
        },
      ]
```

Comment: playOnce is not even a possible props when looking at the library's code

https://i.postimg.cc/FzLxcS3N/Capture-d-e-cran-2022-09-09-a-15-13-52.png

Comment: Can you link the library please?

Comment: Sure, i'm using this one: https://lottiereact.com/

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help someone as myself, instead of "play", use "playOnce"

Comment: this would be better as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

add loop: false to your options object

```
const options = {
    animationData: CMS,
    loop: false
}
```